# In Excel, what formula would calculate the integer average of the last 365 entries in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel document that has recorded temperatures in parts of the world displayed like so:

```
    \|  Fr |  G  |
    -+-----+-----+
    1|  30 | 25  |
    2|  28 | 14  |
    3|  33 | 24  |
    4|  87 | 22  |
    5|  27 | 16  |
        ...
  569|  98 | 34  |
```

I would like to calculate the average temperature for the last 365 entries in a column, but my entries update each day. I want it to determine the last entry in a column, and then average 365 rows up from that if possible.

[image: example]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Where should the result appear?  If you keep adding values, you could display it to the right of the last entry so you don't need to deal with VBA.  Add a formula that averages the values in the range containing that row's value and the preceding 364 rows.  Hide the result unless the next row is empty.  Then you can copy that formula as needed, even pre-populate an arbitrary range for future entries.

Comment: @fixer1234 ![example]http://puu.sh/t32hl/da960f2a73.png

Comment: The results in a fixed location adds another dimension.  I don't have time to develop a solution right now, but look at formulas for finding the last row of a range (lots of examples).  Arithmetic then calculates the first row.  Then use INDIRECT to build your average formula at the top like you've shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### COUNTA to get last row, INDIRECT to get 365 range

As fixer1234 already mentioned in comments, you can use some method to dynamically determine the last row, e.g. `COUNTA`. Then use `INDIRECT` to use that dynamic last row inside a range reference. Like so:

[image]

Alternatively, you can ommit the `OFFSET` part, and build the `INDIRECT` for each column. E.g. `="B"&G2&":B"&F2`, etc... Like so:

[image]